# Why doesn't eslint allow the rule option @typescript-eslint/consistent-type-imports?

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I applied the eslint rule as follows.

```js
module.exports = {
rules: {
 "@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-imports": [
            "error",
            {
                fixStyle: "inline-type-imports"
            }
        ],
}
}
```

After that, I tried to run the fix option using eslint.

```bash
eslint --fix --ext js,ts,tsx .
```

But get error

```
Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 8.26.0

Error: .eslintrc.js:
        Configuration for rule "@typescript-eslint/consistent-type-imports" is invalid:
        Value {"fixStyle":"inline-type-imports"} should NOT have additional properties.

    at ConfigValidator.validateRuleOptions (.../node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc/dist/eslintrc.cjs:2027:23)
    at .../node_modules/@eslint/eslintrc/dist/eslintrc.cjs:2082:18
```

It's an option that's also in the actual [official document](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/consistent-type-imports/), why doesn't it apply?

my package.json

```json
{
"devDependencies": {
"typescript": "4.8.4"
"eslint": "^8.26.0",
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a version issue of something other than the version issue of the packages I presented in the question.

My solution is upgrade version `5.41.0` => `5.59.9`

```json
{
 "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.59.9", 
 "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.59.9",
}
```